# Practical difference between deconvolution and resize followed by convolution for upscaling

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, deconvolution

I need to go (upsample) from a layer `input = HxWxn1`, where H: height, W:width and n1: number of filters, to a layer `output = 2Hx2Wxn2`, where 2H = 2*Height etc, and `n2=n1/2`: number of new filters. One way of achieving this is by using transposed convolution operators. However, it is known that deconvolution (transposed convolution) operators can lead to the [checkerboard artifacts](https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/). One way to overcome this problem is to perform resize and then apply a convolution map. E.g.

```
output = transpose_conv2d(input,n2,kernel!=(1,1),stride!=1)
```

vs

```
output = resize(input) # e.g. bilinear interpolation
output = conv2d(output,n2,kernel=(1,1),stride=1)
```

Obviously, in the second case, we are just changing the number of filters, and we are "not learning" any feature (we do not summarize information from `input` layer). But this can be solved by another convolution with kernel size,  `kernel!= 1`. E.g.

```
output = resize(input)
output = conv2d(output,n2,kernel=(1,1),stride=1)
# appropriate padding
output = conv2d(output, n2, kernel != (1,1), ...)
```

Are there any practical differences (besides computational complexity) between the two approaches for upsampling? I understand that the latter solves the problem of checkerboard artifacts.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I came across this question and was interested. Did you ever manage to notice any differences?

Comment: I ended up going the second direction, where upsampling takes place with resize+convolution. There was not enough time to train all possible combinations and do a thorough comparison between transpose conv and resize+conv. I noticed slight improvement (in my limited tests) with resize+conv, but take it with a grain of salt. Here is the arch I ended up using: https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.00592